# Google street view

Tags: android-studio, google-maps

Давно сделал "бродилку" google street (получал API и т.д.)- всё работало. Через год запустил установленную ранее на телефоне, а на вьюшке лишь чёрный экран, тогда я пошёл на нововведение Гугла в виде предоставление API на платной(кредитной) основе и моё старое приложение вдруг заработало. Но вот беда - запуская ТОТ ЖЕ старый проект в Android Studio - на экране опять отображения чёрный квадрат. В чём проблема?

В добавок заметил такую странность: после запуска в A Studio устанавливая заведомо рабочий apk с этого же проекта - он высвечивает всё тот же чёрный экран, но если программу удалить и установить apk заново, то улица появляется!

По ошибках

При первом запуске программы
Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

В логах:

1) Entry fileTemplates//code/Google Test Fixture SetUp Method.cc.ft not found in /C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/lib/idea.jar

В Android Monitor:

1)E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!

2)E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
com.example.user.googlestreetview13 E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.
!!! ОШИБКА АВТОРИЗАЦИИ? Но как, ведь всё работало и ничего не трогалося, и apk этого же проекта запускается.

3)Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.

4)com.example.user.googlestreetview13 E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)

Ни Android Studio, ни Windows, ни java, НИЧЕГО НЕ менялась. О Manifest'е и разрешениях я в курсе. И самое главное - вариант переустановить студию КАТЕГОРИЧЕСКИ отторгается! (есть причины) Да с ним же всё прекрасно работало.